# WatchConnectivity sharing keys

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

With the new Watch OS 2 and the new Watch Connectivity, it is no longer required to use App Groups to share data between the watch an the iOS app. But how would you avoid duplicating strings in the app and the extension?

For example when sending a message from the watch, you will send a dictionary with a specific key in it.

You need this key in the app to know what was sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define an enum with string raw value and include the file on both targets. I usually put all shared files in a `shared` group, in the project navigator at the same level of the iOS app and watch extension - that makes it clear the files contained there are not specific to a single target.

You can then use that enum to safely use dictionary keys - probably you can also override the subscript operator in a dictionary extension to use the enum instead of its raw value